# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' error

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON coming from one of our REST service:

```
[
    "{\"category_name\":[\"Industry Components\"],\"categoryId\":[1]}",
    "{\"category_name\":[\"Business Components\"],\"categoryId\":[2]}",
    "{\"category_name\":[\"Utilities\"],\"categoryId\":[3]}",
    "{\"category_name\":[\"Tools\"],\"categoryId\":[4]}
]
```

I am using java-json.jar to parse this JSON, this is the simple snippet where I am trying to pass above JSON string:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

But I am getting below exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

First I assumed it's because of `[` and `]` characters in JSON and I tried to replace as below:

```
String replacedStr = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")
```

But even then I am getting same exception. Can anyone please guide me to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing quote on the last line.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I suppose that you should use not JSONObject, but JSONArray

Answer (score 14):

JSON Object follows the following Structure:

```
{
 "array": [
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
}
]
}
```

JSON Array follows the following Structure:

```
[
 { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
 { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
 { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
]
```

Comment: If you're going to embed an array in an object it needs to look like `{ "key": [ value(s) ] }`

Comment: Also I don't have control on the input (ie JSON) which I am receiving. (And I didn't downvote you)

Comment: Thank you for this distinction.

Answer (score 1):

instead

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

use

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

and may be read about Gson is a nice library for parsing and work with json

Answer (score 0):

If you get JSONObject text must begin with '{' exception.
Then first off all check what did u pass to the JSONObject constructor.

You should pass the right json.txt file.So make sure what are u passing to jsonobject.

```
String request = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/home/achaure/Downloads/Amol/KountRestTest/Documents/request.txt"));

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
```