# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am using DuckDuckGo Api and it gives me sometimes that error when parsing the json , I can't find out why .Here is the code I'm using :

```
private String getUrls(String urlapi) throws IOException, JSONException {
            InputStream in = null;
            in = connectTo(urlapi);
            String result = requestResponseAsString(in);
            String fullResult = parseJSON(result);
            return fullResult;

        }

        private String parseJSON(String result) throws JSONException {
            String url = null;
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray arr = jObject.getJSONArray("Results");
            if(arr.length()>0){
                url = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("FirstURL");
                System.out.println(url);}
            return url;
        }
```

Comment: Already looked here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399135/a-jsonobject-text-must-begin-with-error

Comment: Yes and I verified that I'm not making the same mistake , since I always get this :  "Results" : [
      {
         "Result" : "<a href=\"http://www.paris.fr\"><b>Official site</b></a><a href=\"http://www.paris.fr\"></a>",
         "Icon" : {
            "URL" : "https://duckduckgo.com/i/paris.fr.ico",
            "Height" : 16,
            "Width" : 16
         },
         "FirstURL" : "http://www.paris.fr",
         "Text" : "Official site"
      }
   ] as an array and  "FirstURL" : "http://www.paris.fr" as an object

Answer (score 2):

From [A JSONObject text must begin with '{' error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19399202/456814),

> JSON Object follows the following Structure:
>
> ```
> {
>  "array": [
> {
>     color: "red",
>     value: "#f00"
> },
> {
>     color: "green",
>     value: "#0f0"
> }
> ]
> }
> ```
>
> JSON Array follows the following Structure:
>
> ```
> [
>  { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
>  { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
>  { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
> ]
> ```

Comment: . An empty array has to be like this : [{ }] ?

Comment: Empty array is [], [{}] means array with one empty object.

Comment: So how can I get FirstURL from Results(last array) if it's not  arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("FirstURL");

Comment: Please properly cite and quote other people's answers that you copy, otherwise it is plagiarism.

Comment: @Cupcake which answer ??

Comment: @user200099 I didn't mean you, I meant Bernd.